# Have user enter scores or check grade average in 2 dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

Help!
I feel like I am in way over myhead,
I am trying to create a small program to have a user do the following

Pseudo Code

> Import scanner
>
> Define variables numStudents numExams studscore studgrade userIn
>   keepGoing
>
> Ask user how many students, set to numStudents
>
> Ask user how many exams, set to numExams
>
> Create 2 dimensional array studentResults for numstudents numExams
>
> While keepGoing == true
>
> Ask user to Press E to exit, S to enter exam scores for a student,  or
>   C to check a final grade   Parse input as char         If exit, exit
>   program, set keepGoing to false        Else if S, ask for student number,
>   create For statement to have user enter all exam scores and store for
>   that student number        Else if C, ask for student number, display
>   results        Else showmessage, that is not a valid option

*****So far I have this....

I am trying to find out how to have the user input their scores (Asks what their student number is (first array part) then input their exam scores for that student number.

And then part 2, coming back into the while loop, if they select to view final grade, program asks their student number and returns the average of the scores for that student number.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class examgrades {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    //Define variables
    int numStudents=0;
    int numExams=0;
    int studScore=1;
    char studGrade='a';
    int studChoice=1;
    char userChoice;
    boolean keepGoing=true;

    //Get number of students
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of Students: ");
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    numStudents=reader.nextInt();

    //Get number of Exams   
    System.out.println("Thank you, now please enter the number of exams this semester: ");
    Scanner reader1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    numExams=reader1.nextInt();

    //Create array
    int [][] studentResults = new int [numStudents][numExams];

    //Create intial program loop
    while (keepGoing);

        //Ask user to Press S to enter exam scores for a student, C to check a final grade, or E to Exit
        System.out.println("Press S to enter exam scores for a student, C to check a final grade, or E to Exit");
        Scanner reader2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userIn=reader2.nextLine();
        //Parse into Char
        userChoice=userIn.charAt(0);

        //Check for exit
        if (userChoice=='e' || userChoice=='E') {keepGoing=false; System.out.println("Program is exiting... \n");}

        //Enter Scores if User chose S


        //Check final Grade if user chose C
```

Comment: Proper syntax for a while loop:
    `while (keepGoing) {
        ...
    }`

Comment: Put your psuedocode in a code block.

Comment: Unrelated but to save you checking for upper and lower case you could add to your line `String userIn=reader2.nextLine().toLowerCase(); //or .toUpperCase()` then you only have to have one statement in your if conditions

Answer (score 3):

Here'a a hard to catch bug in your code:

```
while (keepGoing);
```

The correct way to declare a loop is this:

```
while (keepGoing) {
    // body
}
```

That `;` at the end of the loop condition has the effect of creating a loop without a body, so nothing is being repeated! the code below the loop is executing exactly once.